# Access Cucumber feature variable in a step defintion with json_spec

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I downloaded the `json_spec` gem and I'm trying to access a variable that was stored in my Cucumber feature file. From the json_spec [readme](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec) it shows that you can store a variable as follows; I keep the JSON response as "USER_1". Is there any way to access this "USER_1" variable for use in my step defintions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
JsonSpec.memory[:USER_1]
```

Will allow you to access the specific stored value. However this is not really documented as supported behaviour and as such constitutes an implementation detail that is subject to change. So i wouldn't rely on it.

And additionally you should always be able to access the actual JSON as `last_json`, which is the method you need to provide for *json_spec* to work. If i needed to do something with the response (e.g. to issue additional requests) i would parse `last_json` myself.

The code for the JsonSpec memory can be found [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec/blob/master/lib/json_spec/memory.rb). And the usage of it during the step-definition can be seen [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec/blob/master/lib/json_spec/cucumber.rb#L10).

Comment: Worked like a charm... thanks! I'll keep in mind that it may be changing and move towards parsing the JSON for the long term. Nice for a quick fix in the mean time.